# Button to skip html5 video to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video player which contain a skip button so that the user can skip the video to the end.

Here is html

```
<video id="video1" style="height: 100%" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls muted autoplay="true">
            </video>
```

skip function

```
function skipVideoTime(){
    $('.skip_button').on('click', function () {
        var vid = $("#video1")[0];
        var vidDuration = Math.floor(vid.duration);
        skipTime(vidDuration);
        console.log(vidDuration);

    })

}

function skipTime(time) {
    var vid = $("#video1")[0];
    vid.play();
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = time;
    vid.play();
    console.log(vid.duration);
};

$(function () {

     skipVideoTime();


});
```

Here is console logs from the above functions

`32.534`

`32`

Now when I click the button it skip to 32 minutes because I used math floor function if I remove math floor so that it can skip to `32.534`, it does not work,

what do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: As far as I can guess, you are trying to seek the media / video at the end of its time. e.g. 32.534 sec. after that you are again calling `play()` function which I think will play the video again from start. Do you really need to call `vid.play()` after seeking the media till its duration ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you don't need to call the `play()` function again. because once media is seeked to the end (till its total duration), calling `play()` will do nothing but run the video again from beginning. Have a look at following code snippet.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 console.log(video.duration);
 video.play();
 video.pause();
 video.currentTime = video.duration;
//  video.play();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

 <video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls id="myvid"></video>
 <button id="button">skip</button>
</body>
</html>
```